# Detection of pattern of circles using opencv

Tags: image-processing, opencv, pattern-matching, computer-vision, object-recognition

I have to detect the pattern of 6 circles using opencv. I have detected the circles and their centroids by using thresholding and contour function in opencv.

Now I have to define the relation between these circles in a way that should be invariant to scale and rotation. With this I would be able to detect this pattern in various views. I have to use this pattern for determining the object pose.

How can I achieve scale/rotation invariance? Do you have any reference I could read about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing robust (color and size invariant) circle detection with opencv (based on Hough transform or other features)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860667/writing-robust-color-and-size-invariant-circle-detection-with-opencv-based-on)

Comment: You may want to look into point matching or image registration. Also, a simple way to get a translation and rotation invariant description of your points might to compute the positions relative to a pair of points. For example by normalizing the distance between those two points to 1 and rotating it to a degree of zero. Then of course you need to find the exact same pair in your second set of points. But with just 6 points in total it might be feasible to test all possible combinations.

Comment: It would be better if you could add your image here. Or upload image in imageshack.us and give link here.

Comment: @sietschie i have tried normalized moments and Hu moments to get invariant features of individual circle, but how to do it for the whole pattern for circles? and you told to normalized the distance to one and angle to zero, can you explain it more? i know normalization of vector which give us unit step, but in this case how to use this information to detect pattern?

Comment: @arkiaz here is the link for the pattern that i am trying to detect,http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/5852/patterndetect.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your pattern invariant toward rotation & scale, you have to normalize the direction and the scale when detecting your pattern. Here is a simple algorithm to achieve this

- detect centers and circle size (you say you have already achieved this - good!)
- compute the average center using a simple mean. Express all the centers from this mean
- find the farthest center using a simple norm (euclidian is good enough)
- scale the center position and the circle sizes so that this maximum distance is 1.0
- rotate the centers so that coordinates of the farthest one is (1.0, 0)

you're done. You are now the proud owner of a scale/rotation invariant pattern detector!! Congratulations!

Now you can find patterns, transform them as suggested, and compare center position & circle sizes.

Comment: thanks you very much for such a detailed and , well explained answer I now understand how to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me if you need to find the rotation, or merely get rid of it, or detect if the circles actually form the pattern you linked. Either way, the answer is much the same.

I would start by finding the two circles that have only one neighbour. For each circle centroid calculate the distance to the closest two neighbours. If the distances differ in more than say 10%, the centroid belongs to an "end" circle (one of the top ones in your link).

Now that you have found the two end circles, rotate them so that they are horizontal to each other. If the other centroids are now above them, rotate another 180 degrees so that the pattern ends up in the orientation you want.

Now you can calculate the scaling from the average inter-centroid distance.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, your comments really helped me to understand the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds exactly like what the SURF algorithm does.  It finds groups of interest and groups them together in a way invarant to rotation and scale, and can find the same object in other pictures.

Just search for OpenCV and SURF.