# Reading dots of a dice using Hough circles

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I have an image of a dice. I want to count the number of dots. I first tried just separating it using the color of the dots and reading the number of connected paths. But it is failing since the photo contains a tilted image of the side face also. So I tried Hough circles.

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(detected_edges, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, circles, 105, 10, 10, 15)
```

This is the code I tried. But it is not detecting the correct circles. When I looked the diameter of the dots, it was around 12-15 pixels and the minimum distance between the pixels were 14-16 pixels. I am not sure about setting the `param1` and `param2` values. As I saw in the documentation, I used 105 since it worked for `Canny` method. Can somone help me in resolving this?

Comment: I went through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716464/what-are-the-correct-usage-parameter-values-for-houghcircles-in-opencv-for-iris/10718967#10718967) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276390/houghcircles-parameters-to-recognise-balls). But it didn't help me.

Comment: Why don't you share the picture of your dice, so that your test-case becomes more clear to us.

Comment: I don't have enough credits to post an image.

Comment: Ok. I haven't seen your image. How about you first detect the top-face of your dice, and use your first technique for getting the number of dots only in top-face region.

Comment: I don't have any idea to selectively detect only the top face, because the position of the dice is not fixed.

Comment: I have shared the test image [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nihd5nrj3rpn00n/image.jpeg)

Comment: Hm. If it is sure, that the dice is always lighter than the surrounding region, I would try to find maximums of lightness in the _blurred_ image. Then I would search for dots within a certain radius around these maximums.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I tried your logic and its working fine. But I wish to try hough circles. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I preprocessed the image extracting only the light color of the dice. Then I applied connected component labeling to the result. The application is working fine. But I would wish to know how to implement this using Hough Circles.

Answer (score 0):

I would try decreasing your minimum radius to around 5 if your dots have diameter 12-15 pixels and ditto max radius could be smaller e.g. 8 and increase your param2 to around 20.
Also are you blurring before applying the detection?