# cv2.HoughCircles detects many fake circles but the actual ones

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am struggling a bit with openCV, trying to detect circles on an image. Circles are drawn with a pen on a white sheet

I'm trying to use `cv2.HoughCircles`  but the results are very unreliable. Both on grayscale and on binary images this algorithm fails to find circles. At the same time finding a lot of fake ones

Here are the examples

[image: Here only fake circles are detected]

[image: A lot of fake circles]

[image: Original image]

I tried to apply binarization and finding contours. That worked fine except any noise was considered a contour and slowed down the program significantly.

With `cv2.HoughCircles` I tired to play with parameters (param1, param2). At low param 2 it starts to detect but at the same time detects many fake ones somewhere in an empty spots. with a bit higher param2 only fake circles are detected.

What's is wrong? May be my circles are not circle enough?

Comment: _"May be my circles are not circle enough"_ . . .  love it !!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is struggling to detect those circles is due to `param2`, the accumulator threshold. What this does is adjusts the number of circles that will be detected by the code. The lower it is, the more circles will be detected and output, based on the most accurate/confident detections. Somehow, `cv2.HoughCircles` is not detecting your drawn circles very accurately. With a low `param2`, you'll also have more false detections, which is clearly observed.

The solution involves lots of preprocessing, which I won't get into here. But there's a beautiful thread about the use of `cv2.HoughCircles` here with tricks for how to best use it: [Writing robust (color and size invariant) circle detection with OpenCV (based on Hough transform or other features)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860667/writing-robust-color-and-size-invariant-circle-detection-with-opencv-based-on)

Hope this helps!